# Updating a Google Sheets via Python and recognise as a user edit

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-api

I currently working on a project, where I fetch data out of an external API into Google Sheets. Therefore, I created a sheet where I can insert an ID and the data will be fetched via Google Script on a different Sheet automatically. In order to automate this task I created a Drive-API which can be accessed by my local python. Furthermore, I figured out how to change specific cells. 
But here comes the struggle. Since the update is not recognised as user edit change all my triggers in the google script are not working, because they are triggered through an onChange trigger. 
My current python code looks like this:

Python Code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account 
import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open('APP_ID_X').sheet1

data = sheet.update_cell(2,1, "10")
```

First Trigger in GAS:

```
function onEdit(e){
    if (e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getName() !== 'APP_ID' || e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.range.rowStart != 2) return;
    e.range.offset(0, 1)
        .setValue(typeof e.value == 'object' ? null : new Date());
  schedTrigger();
}
```

I would highly appreciate if someone would have an idea how to solve my struggle!? 
Many thanks in advance

Best,
Crov

Answer (score 0):

If you could insert a row at the end of your "update" that should fire the onChange event and then perhaps you could complete all of you trigger actions at one time.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I was considering that solution too but the onEdit Trigger is mandatory to set a time in the cell next to the ID-cell. Therefore, I cannot leave out the onEdit trigger. Do you have a different solution to it? I also included the GAS Trigger, hopefully it makes it more clear.